# Is there a way to set the aggression for the OS X Diablo Minor?

Tags: miner-configuration, mac, gpu-mining, diablominer

I run the OS X Diablo Minor on my new Macbook.  It seems to work well enough and it earns me a few bit-cents each day.

The only problem is that I have to cut it off whenever I'm working on the Mac, because it hogs the GPU.  Is there a parameter or some config file within the .app bundle that I can modify that will reduce the aggression level so I can use my Mac and mine with unused GPU cycles?

Answer (score 1):

There's really no point in mining on a MacBook. It'll get super hot and the GPU will be totally bogged down. If you reduce the aggression, then you kill the point of mining altogether on your machine.

Comment: Well, my point is, I don't want to have to start/stop the minor as I move to and from my Macbook (I have a couple PCs I use on a day-to-day basis.)  Also, my electricity is free, so there is a point to mine when I'm making $.15/day-- it's free money and all I have to do is start an application! :)  The GPU does get hot, but I haven't had any problems.  If I just want a way to change the aggression or thread priority, so that when I'm using XCode, the interface doesn't act "jerky".

Comment: @RLH _electricity_ may be free, but the MacBook itself is free too? Mining constantly will reduce its lifetime, so it's not free. Also, _your time_ isn't free either: if you spend it setting up a miner, you could spend it doing something more profitable instead.

Comment: Regardless of my reasons, these comments are irrelevant to the question.  I'm not stating this to incite and argument but, regardless of my intent, asking if setting the aggression  is still a valid question to ask.  I request related answers please.  I know using the GPU is hard with excessive heat is hard on the PC.  Still, I'd like to have either an answer that changes the aggression or explicitly states from a knowledgeable source whether it is possible or not.

Comment: Also, let me quickly state that I do appreciate the concern.  Had I not known about the issues with the heat, they would have helped a ton.  However, I am still interested in the answer to my question, regardless of the consequences.

Comment: @RLH sure it is a valid question, in fact I upvoted it. It was important to point out these problems, though, and due to the circumstances this can be easily considered a fine answer, too (though I understand you would like a more strict _answer_, of course).

Comment: @Lohoris how does mining constantly reduce the MacBook's lifetime? Any proof?

Comment: @asymmetric standard wear, overheating an electronic component, especially if for a prolonged span of time, and even more if on a device as small as a laptop, reduces its lifespan.